# Is there real documentation for @google-cloud/iot API?

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-iot

The JavaScript module "@google-cloud/iot" doesn't seem to much resemble its documentation here (https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/iot/latest/index.html).

For example, the function `client.sendCommandToDevice()` is documented to return type `SendCommandToDeviceResponse`, while it actually returns a complex intersection of interfaces and undefineds. I can find the right type buried in a nest of namespaces inside the module, but even then I can't manage to get the data I need from the result. For example, the ...Response type has a static function "toJSON()" that takes a Response and returns JSON--but it won't take the actual response object, and I can't find any way to convert the actual response object into the expected type.

This isn't the only such error. Is this perhaps an artifact of over-hastily converting an old JavaScript API to TypeScript without checking to see that it's actually usable in TypeScript?  Is there perhaps some documentation on the older JavaScript API that I might look at to compare?

Here's a code snippet (before transpilation):

```
// node 14.17.3, TypeScript 4.4.4, iot 2.5.1

import iot from "@google-cloud/iot";
// Yes, I did the credentials thing...
const client = new iot.v1.DeviceManagerClient();

function generateRequest(id: string, data: any) {
    const formattedName = client.devicePath("myproject", "us-central1", "myregistry", id);
    const binData = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)).toString("base64");

    return {
        ok: true,
        name: formattedName,
        binData: binData,
    };
}

async function run() {
    const project = await client.getProjectId();
    const parent = client.locationPath(project, 'us-central1');

    const deviceId = "d99999995";
    const data = { get: [ "program" ] };
    const request = generateRequest(deviceId, data);

    let r = await client.sendCommandToDevice(request);
    // what is r here???

    /* Same issue with, e.g.:
    client.updateDevice();
    client.modifyCloudToDeviceConfig()
    */
    return {
        ok: true,
        result: r,
    };
}

run().catch((err) => { console.error(err); });
```

Comment: Your question is a good example of no details. Provide an example of the problem that you are having. Include the versions of important items like the library, node, tsc, etc. It is a lot easier to get a good answer if we can simply copy and paste your example and then use our experience to help you solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for resonding -- I'm not sure what kind of detail you're looking for. The specifically named function (sendCommandToDevice, as well as others like updateDevice and modifyCloudToDeviceConfig) are documented to return a specific type, and they don't. There are documented functions on that type I'd like to call, but I can't, because the return isn't one of them. What's not clear?

Comment: By providing example code with details, I don't have to guess what code you have written, which version of the library to include, which version of the tools to install to duplicate your problem. Read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If I read the docs correctly ... https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/iot/latest/google.cloud.iot.v1.DeviceManager.html#sendCommandToDevice2 ... what a call to sendCommandToDevice returns is *not* a SendCommandToDeviceResponse but instead is a JavaScript Promise that, when resolved ... resolves to a SendCommandToDeviceResponse.

Comment: Well, yes, it's a promise--I knew that part. It resolves to an undocumented complex union type. I've added code. I'd just like to know if the call succeeded; that info is in the documented return type, but I don't know how to get it from the actual return.

Comment: Could you share the response returned by `sendCommandToDevice` method and your desired return type within that response?

Comment: The value returned is of this type, taken directly from the source code: `Promise< [protos.google.cloud.iot.v1.ISendCommandToDeviceResponse, protos.google.cloud.iot.v1.ISendCommandToDeviceRequest | undefined, {} | undefined]>`

Comment: Did you checkout this [link](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/iot/latest/google.cloud.iot.v1.SendCommandToDeviceResponse.html),the response provides different methods to retrieve return type.

Comment: @Ash_max That link is to the constructor of the supposed return type of the function. How is that relevant in any way to the function in question? Sure, I can build one--but I don't want a new one, I want the one I was promised by the function.

Answer (score 1):

> **Immediate feedback**: your responses to the commenters show your evident frustration. I think it's reasonable to assume that people don't take time to respond to your question to frustrate you. I was reluctant to reply to, not wishing to also be chastised, but like them I want to try to help you...

The documentation for the library appears correct but I'm neither a TypeScript nor JavaScript guru. I am very familiar with GCP and its services and writing client code.

Google has been evolving its services to reflect its internal widespread use of gRPC. It appears to me that some of this move towards more gRPC-native services is bleeding through into its SDKs (viz the preponderance of protobuf messages) and I find this confusing especially because I've not seen it fully explained.

In the case of [`@google-cloud/iot`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/iot) the methods do reference protobuf messages. So, your [`sendCommandToDevice`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/iot/latest/google.cloud.iot.v1.DeviceManager.html#sendCommandToDevice2) method has a signature which takes a [`SendCommandToDeviceRequest`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/iot/latest/google.cloud.iot.v1.ISendCommandToDeviceRequest.html) and returns a Promised [`SendCommandToDeviceResponse`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/iot/latest/google.cloud.iot.v1.SendCommandToDeviceResponse.html).

As I say, I'm unfamiliar with TypeScript but, in JavaScript (sic.), I wonder whether you must use the `SendCommandToDeviceRequest` constructor to create your request:

```
function generateRequest(id, data) {
    const formattedName = client.devicePath("myproject", "us-central1", "myregistry", id);
    const binaryData = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)).toString("base64");

    return {
        name: formattedName,
        binaryData: binaryData,
    };
}

const rqst = new iot.protos.google.cloud.iot.v1.SendCommandToDeviceRequest(
  generateRequest(deviceId, data)
);
```

> **NOTE** The property is `binaryData` not `binData`

Then, since it's `await`'ed, I think your response type will be `SendCommandToDeviceResponse`:

```
const resp = await client.sendCommandToDevice(rqst);
```

@Ash_max referenced this type in the comments. Although the constructor is listed at the top of the page, lower down the page is [`toJSON()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/iot/latest/google.cloud.iot.v1.SendCommandToDeviceResponse.html#toJSON). So you should be able to:

```
console.log(`response: ${resp.toJSON()}`);
```

> maybe `JSON.stringify(resp.toJSON())`

I've not time to try this today but I'll try to repro your experience tomorrow and update this thread.

##### Update

I created a GCP project, registry and device.

I ran the Node.JS code outlined above and the return type is confusing; I'm getting an array of 3 objects, the first of which looks to be a proto but doesn't support `toJSON` and I can't get it `toString()` either.

So, I looked at [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) and according to it [sendCommandToDevice](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/cloudiot/rest/v1/projects.locations.registries.devices/sendCommandToDevice) (which I take as definitive), the response body will be empty on success.

Confused, I wrote the equivalent Golang program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    b64 "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "google.golang.org/api/cloudiot/v1"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := cloudiot.NewService(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    rqst := &cloudiot.SendCommandToDeviceRequest{
        BinaryData: b64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte("Hello Freddie")),
    }

    name := fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s/locations/%s/registries/%s/devices/%s",
        os.Getenv("PROJECT"),
        os.Getenv("REGION"),
        os.Getenv("REGISTRY"),
        os.Getenv("DEVICE"),
    )

    devices := client.Projects.Locations.Registries.Devices
    resp, err := devices.SendCommandToDevice(name, rqst).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Printf("%+v", resp)
}
```

And its `resp` is definitely of type `SendCommandToDeviceResponse` and, contains `ServerResponse` which includes the `HTTPStatusCode`:

```
&{
  ServerResponse:{
    HTTPStatusCode:200
    Header:map[
      Cache-Control:[private]
      Content-Type:[application/json; charset=UTF-8]
      Date:[Wed, 20 Oct 2021 00:20:00 GMT]
      Server:[ESF] Vary:[Origin X-Origin Referer]
      X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff]
      X-Frame-Options:[SAMEORIGIN]
      X-Xss-Protection:[0]
    ]
  }
}
```

So, the JavaScript (Node.JS|TypeScript) code should somehow (!) be able to grab that `ServerResponse` too from the `SendCommandToDeviceResponse`.

The documentation appears to be correct.

Comment: Many, many, thanks for taking the time to respond--I don't mean to take my frustration out on those who might be helpful. Your code above is pretty much exactly what I've been trying to do, and failing, because the JavaScript API simply does not return the value it is documented to return, as apparently the Golang API does. I will try turning off basically all of TypeScript and use the old typeless API to see if that will allow me to at least get the data. I may even accept your answer if it helps me get there. In the meantime, I've entered a formal bug report.

Comment: You're very welcome. Thank you! I suspect there is an issue but I am getting a response from the method, I'm just unable to decode it correctly. There may (!) be a trick. I'm not getting an error from the call and my Golang client device is receiving the command. Please include a reference to the issuetracker here. I wonder whether someone else is able to explain how to do the equivalent of Golang's `resp.ServerResponse`.

Comment: Found it: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-iot/issues/524